# Запуск скрипта JS в условии PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день. У меня есть условие на PHP. И нужно если это условие срабатывало то активировалась функция JS

```
if($num == "2")
{
Срабатывает функция JS
}
```

Сама функция JS

```
function test12(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'myscript3.php',
            data : { OKEY3: 'OKTI3' },
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });         
 };
```

Я пытался поместить JS в условие но он все равно не срабатывал.

Comment: Приведенного JS кода не достаточно, что бы что то происходило. Вы просто определили функцию... А вызов этой функции есть?

Answer (score 3):

PHP работает на стороне сервера, JS на стороне посетителя и между ними нет ни какой прямой связи. PHP лишь генерирует страницу. все... 
Единственная примерная возможность решить вашу задачу (не глядя, что сама по себе она неправильная). Гененрировать страницу в соответствии с условием

```
<?if ($num==2):?>
<script>
 function test2(){
  ....
 };
 test2();
</script>
<?endif?>
```

Т.е. скрипт выводится на страницу, тольков случае выполнения условия.

Но я бы, на вашем месте, подумал над правильностью постановки задачи.

Answer (score 1):

например вот так

```
<?if($num == "2"){?> 
<script>
     test12();
</script>
<?}?>
```